# Was the Object superclass removed from LÖVE?

Tags: lua, love2d

The documentation makes reference to an [Object](https://love2d.org/wiki/Object) superclass. However, when I run the example on the [Object:typeOf](https://love2d.org/wiki/Object:typeOf) page, it outputs `false` for `print(image:typeOf("Object"))` instead of `true`. I also tried it with [Canvas](https://love2d.org/wiki/Canvas) and it too returned `false`.

Is this a bug or was the class removed? If so, does anyone know which version it was removed in?

I'm using 0.10.2, Super Toast.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It wasn't removed, at least not in C++. I compared the code from an old 2010  mirror on github with the latest source in Bitbucket and Image still inherits from Object:

GitHub: [Image : Drawable](https://github.com/love2d/love/blob/master/src/modules/graphics/Image.h#L34) and [Drawable : Object](https://github.com/love2d/love/blob/master/src/modules/graphics/Drawable.h#L35)

BitBucket: [Image : Texture](https://bitbucket.org/rude/love/src/default/src/modules/graphics/opengl/Image.h?at=default&fileviewer=file-view-default#Image.h-51) and [Texture : Drawable](https://bitbucket.org/rude/love/src/default/src/modules/graphics/Texture.h?at=default&fileviewer=file-view-default#Texture.h-39) and [Drawable : Object](https://bitbucket.org/rude/love/src/default/src/modules/graphics/Drawable.h?at=default&fileviewer=file-view-default#Drawable.h-36)

How that is exposed to Lua and why `typeOf()` doesn't return what the documentation says it should return, I don't know. I would file that as a bug, since the docs say it should return `true` for Object (at the least, it's a documentation error).